# Решение задачи о рюкзаке методом divide-and-conquer ("разделяй и властвуй")

Tags: алгоритм, рекурсия

Есть задание: написать программу решающую задачу о неограниченном рюкзаке методом "разделяй и властвуй".

Справка для пущих незнаек, нежели я:

Парадигма "разделяй и властвуй" заключается в рекурсивном разделении задачи на две или более подзадачи одного типа и соединении результатов этих подзадач в единое решение задачи.

Задача о неограниченном рюкзаке: есть рюкзак вместительности *М*, а также предметы размера *a[i]* и ценностью *b[i]*. Нужно найти такой набор предметов, чтобы он поместился в рюкзак и его ценность была максимальной. Рюкзак неограниченный (дано произвольное количество экземпляров каждого предмета).

Не могу сообразить, как можно решить задачу данным методом. Каким образом можно разделить задачу? Как учесть, что в рюкзаке может быть несколько предметов одного типа? У кого какие есть мысли? Программу прошу не присылать, только объяснение!

Comment: Какой же он неограниченный, если имеет вместимость M? :) А если всерьез - то почему вы решили решать именно этим методом? Это что, учебное задание такое?

Comment: @Harry, да задание учебное, нужно именно этим методом. А неограниченность меня тоже с толку изначально сбила, но таково определение: неограниченность распространяется именно на число имеющихся предметов.